# How to complete restful api query with rust and actix-web?

Tags: rest, rust, serde, actix-web

I have some data, from the request's querystring, the structure like this:

Crates: `serde_qs` `serde`  `mongodb` and its `serde_helpers`

```json
filter: {
  linkOperator: "and", // maybe 'or'
  items: [
    {
      field: "parent",
      operator: "is", // maybe 'isNot', 'isAnyOf' 
      value: "id"
    },
    {
      field: "createdAt",
      operator: "is", // maybe 'before', 'after', .etc
      value: "RFC 3339 string"
    }
  ]
}
```

I use the `serde` crate to handle it, the `linkOperator` as `enum`, `items` as its type. I use the mongodb as the database.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, PartialEq)]
#[serde(tag = "linkOperator", content = "items", rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub enum Filter<T> {
    And(Vec<T>),
    Or(Vec<T>),
}

pub trait ToFilter {
    fn to_filter(self) -> Document;
}

impl<T> Filter<T> {
    pub fn to_filter(self) -> Document
    where
        T: ToFilter,
    {
        match self {
            Filter::And(items) => {
                let mut filter = vec![];
                for item in items {
                    filter.push(item.to_filter());
                }
                doc! {
                    "$and": filter
                }
            }
            Filter::Or(items) => {
                let mut filter = vec![];
                for item in items {
                    filter.push(item.to_filter());
                }
                doc! {
                    "$or": filter
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I further process it in the next progress. This `enum` is used to handle `datetime`. Use the content of the vec above. `operator` field as `enum`, `value` field as enum's inner type.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, PartialEq)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase", tag = "operator", content = "value")]
pub enum DateTimeFilter {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_bson_datetime_from_rfc3339_string")]
    Is(DateTime),
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_bson_datetime_from_rfc3339_string")]
    Not(DateTime),
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_bson_datetime_from_rfc3339_string")]
    After(DateTime),
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_bson_datetime_from_rfc3339_string")]
    OnOrAfter(DateTime),
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_bson_datetime_from_rfc3339_string")]
    Before(DateTime),
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_bson_datetime_from_rfc3339_string")]
    OnOrBefore(DateTime),
    IsEmpty,
    IsNotEmpty,
}

impl DateTimeFilter {
    pub fn to_filter(self, field: &'static str) -> Document {
        match self {
            DateTimeFilter::Is(value) => doc! { field: value },
            DateTimeFilter::Not(value) => doc! { field: { "$ne": value } },
            DateTimeFilter::After(value) => doc! { field: { "$gt": value } },
            DateTimeFilter::OnOrAfter(value) => doc! { field: { "$gte": value } },
            DateTimeFilter::Before(value) => doc! { field: { "$lt": value } },
            DateTimeFilter::OnOrBefore(value) => doc! { field: { "$lte": value } },
            DateTimeFilter::IsEmpty => doc! { field: { "$exists": false } },
            DateTimeFilter::IsNotEmpty => doc! { field: { "$exists": true } },
        }
    }
}
```

There are some other enums which have a similar effect.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, PartialEq)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase", tag = "operator", content = "value")]
pub enum SingleSelectFilter<T> {
    Is(T),
    Not(T),
    IsAnyOf(Vec<T>),
}

impl<T> SingleSelectFilter<T> {
    pub fn to_filter(self, field: &'static str) -> Document
    where
        Bson: From<T> + From<Vec<T>>,
    {
        match self {
            SingleSelectFilter::Is(value) => doc! { field: value },
            SingleSelectFilter::Not(value) => doc! { field: { "$ne": value } },
            SingleSelectFilter::IsAnyOf(values) => doc! { field: { "$in": values } },
        }
    }
}
```

I combine them.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, PartialEq)]
pub struct PostQuery {
    filter: Option<Filter<FilterField>>,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    sort: Option<Sort<SortField>>,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    pagination: Pagination,
}

/// add the new field here
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, PartialEq)]
#[serde(tag = "field", rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub enum FilterField {
    Published(SingleSelectFilter<bool>),
    PublishedAt(DateTimeFilter),
    CreatedAt(DateTimeFilter),
    Creator(SingleSelectFilter<ObjectId>),
}

impl ToFilter for FilterField {
    fn to_filter(self) -> Document {
        match self {
            FilterField::Published(filter) => filter.to_filter("published"),
            FilterField::PublishedAt(filter) => filter.to_filter("publishedAt"),
            FilterField::CreatedAt(filter) => filter.to_filter("createdAt"),
            FilterField::Creator(filter) => filter.to_filter("creator"),
        }
    }
}
```

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, Clone)]
pub struct AggregatedPost {
    #[serde(rename = "_id")]
    id: ObjectId,
    title: String,
    slug: String,
    content: String,
    categories: Vec<Category>,
    tags: Vec<Tag>,
    #[serde(rename = "publishedAt")]
    published_at: DateTime,
    published: bool,
    #[serde(rename = "createdAt")]
    created_at: DateTime,
    pub creator: User,
}
```

```rust
pub async fn aggregate_posts(
        query: PostQuery,
        service: &Service,
    ) -> Result<(u64, Vec<Self>), AppError> {
        let filter = match query.filter {
            Some(filter) => filter.to_filter(),
            None => doc! {},
        };

        let skip = query.pagination.skip();
        let limit = query.pagination.limit();

        let options = CountOptions::builder().skip(skip).limit(limit).build();
        let count = service
            .count::<Self>(filter.clone(), options, "posts")
            .await?;

        let mut pipeline = vec![
            doc! {
                "$match": filter
            },
            doc! {
                "$skip": skip as u32
            },
            doc! {
                "$limit": limit as u32
            },
            doc! {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "categories",
                    "localField": "categories",
                    "foreignField": "_id",
                    "as": "categories"
                }
            },
            doc! {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "tags",
                    "localField": "tags",
                    "foreignField": "_id",
                    "as": "tags"
                }
            },
            doc! {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "users",
                    "localField": "creator",
                    "foreignField": "_id",
                    "as": "creator"
                }
            },
            doc! {
                "$unwind": {
                    "path": "$creator",
                    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
                }
            },
        ];

        if query.sort.is_some() {
            let sort = query.sort.unwrap().to_sort();
            pipeline.insert(1, doc! { "$sort": sort });
        }

        match service
            .aggregate_docs::<Self>(pipeline, None, "posts")
            .await
        {
            Ok(posts) => Ok((count, posts)),
            Err(error) => Err(error),
        }
    }
```

Use this is a router handler with `serde_qs`

```rust
pub async fn aggregate_posts(
    session: Session,
    service: Data<Service>,
    query: QsQuery<PostQuery>,
) -> Result<HttpResponse, AppError> {
    let user = protect(&session, &service).await?;

    user.has_permission(
        Permission::ReadAggregatedPosts,
        "You don't have permission to get aggregated posts.",
    )?;

    let (count, posts) = AggregatedPost::aggregate_posts(query.into_inner(), &service).await?;

    let posts_json = posts
        .into_iter()
        .map(|post| post.into_json(&user))
        .collect::<Vec<Value>>();

    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(json!({ "count": count, "posts": posts_json })))
}
```

Finally, the problem arises. When I receive a request with a query like this.

```json
filter: {
  linkOperator: "and", // maybe 'or'
  items: [
    {
      field: "published",
      operator: "isAnyOf", // maybe 'before', 'after', .etc
      value: [true]
    }
  ]
}
```

My query error handler will generate the message like this. `Custom("invalid type: string \"true\", expected a boolean")`

```rust
pub fn query_error_handler(error: serde_qs::Error, _req: &HttpRequest) -> Error {
    let app_error = match &error {
        serde_qs::Error::Custom(message) => BadRequest(format!("Query params: {}.", message)),
        _ => BadRequest("Invalid query params.".to_string()),
    };

    InternalError::from_response(error, app_error.error_response()).into()
}
```

My api test result
[image]

How can i convert the string to a bool value here?  Or, have any other options to complete a query in restful api with actix-web?

Comment: Are you certain you didn't accidentially pass in `"true"` instead of `true` as the value? Also if you create a [mre] emphasis of *minimal* you're way more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: I added my api test results， thanks

Comment: I am new to rust, and it seems that rust can't deserialize bool from string. I don't know why there is a `true` string here.

Comment: Because you specify it as string in your request, get parameters are always strings afaik. Might be that you have to implement `Deserialize` (for `SingleSelectFilter`‽) yourself.

Comment: I see. I'm completely self-taught in programming. I really don't know the parameters are strings. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'll try to implement `Deserialize` (for `SingleSelectFilter<T>` generic). I'm a little confused. I don't know how to implement for generic. Thanks.